# How to detect Screen Sharing is enabled, and stop it, my code working for google meet, but it not working for MS Teams

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, display-manager

```
val displayManager =
       applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE) as DisplayManager
    val var1: Array<Display> = displayManager.displays
    val var2 =displayManager.getDisplays(DisplayManager.DISPLAY_CATEGORY_PRESENTATION)

    Log.i("SIze1",""+var1.size.toString())
    Log.i("SIze2",""+var2.size.toString())
```

This is my code for Display Screens, Its working properly for Google meet but not working for MS Teams, what i need to do?, It's happening on all android versions and teams app.

Comment: Maybe it's not even a problem with your code? Also, MS teams running on what OS and which version (app or browser)?

Comment: we tested on android 10,11,etc happening on all android OS, MS Teams app we are testing with, which is downloaded from playstore.